# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool' Error in conditional operation in TemplateField's ItemTemplate

Tags: html, .net

I want to visible div if my condition is satisfied.
I use various way but it's give me an error.
"Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'"
what should i do for it?

I am working with Gridview

It's give me build time error.

> ```
> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock">
>     <ItemTemplate>
>         <div id="divfake" visible='<%# ((Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AlertQty")) < Convert.ToInt32(Eval("InHandStock"))) ? "true" : "False") %>' runat="server">
>               <%# Eval("InHandStock")%>
>         </div>
>     </ItemTemplate> 
> </asp:TemplateField>
> ```

Comment: is it gridview or repeater ?

Comment: Your output would be "true" or "False", both are string. So it will not work. Also your check condition is not correct. What do you want to do with these two integers? `Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AlertQty"))`  `Convert.ToInt32(Eval("InHandStock"))) `

Comment: Sorry I change in content please check.

Comment: I want to hide or show my div with making condition on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="divfake" visible='<%#GetDivVisibility(Eval("AlertQty"),Eval("InHandStock"))%>'>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Just add this function, inside C# with public access level

```
  public bool GetDivVisibility(object alertQty, object inHandStock)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(alertQty) < Convert.ToInt32(inHandStock) ? true : false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your values in `HiddenFields` and change your `div` into a `Panel` control.

```
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfAlertQty" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("AlertQty") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfInHandStock" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("InHandStock") %>' />
                <asp:Panel ID="divfake" runat="server">
                    <%# Eval("InHandStock")%>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then on your codebehind,

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) //check condition for each row and set visibility of the Panel
{
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) //do the following for rows that only have the data
    {
        HiddenField hfAlert = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfAlertQty"); //looks for the value of alert in HiddenField
        HiddenField hfStock = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfInHandStock"); //looks for the value of stock in HiddenField

        Panel div = (Panel)row.FindControl("divFake"); //looks for the Panel to hide / show

        if(Convert.ToInt32(hfAlert.Value) < Convert.ToInt32(hfStock.Value)) //if alert is lesser than the stock hide, else show
        {
            div.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            div.Visible = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div id="divfake" visible='<%= ((Convert.ToInt32(Eval("AlertQty")) < 
Convert.ToInt32(Eval("InHandStock"))) ? "visible" : "hidden") %>' runat="server">
```

I guess that your Eval and Convert.ToInt32 are returning correct values.

Comment: Yes, Error is same

Comment: Yes, I try twice